# width of sidebar and width of text

Tags: beamer

I'm having a slight problem with the width of the sidebar and the width of the text in the sidebar using beamer.

[image]

As seen here, I have manually set the width of the sidebar to 2.9cm, but while there are plenty of room, the text in the sidebar (which currently acts as a table of contents) are still a fixed size, hence some items taking up two lines instead of one.

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % UFT8 - danske bogstaver
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\usepackage{asymptote}

\usetheme{Hannover}
\usecolortheme{rose}
%\useoutertheme{infolines}

\def\swidth{2.2cm}
\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=\swidth}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}
{
  {\usebeamerfont{title in sidebar}%
    \vskip1.5em%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{title in sidebar}%
    \insertshorttitle[width=\swidth,center,respectlinebreaks]\par%
    \vskip1.25em%
  }%
  {%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{author in sidebar}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in sidebar}%
    \insertshortauthor[width=\swidth,center,respectlinebreaks]\par%
        \vskip1.25em%
      }%
      \hbox to2cm{\hss\insertlogo\hss}
      \vskip1.25em%
      \insertverticalnavigation{\swidth}%
      \vfill
      \hbox to2cm{\hskip0.6cm\usebeamerfont{subsection in
          sidebar}\strut\usebeamercolor[fg]{subsection in
          sidebar}\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber\hfill}%
      \vskip3pt%
}%



\title{Teknikfags-eksamen}
\date{}
\author{Philip Jakobsen}

\setbeamersize{sidebar width left = 2.9cm}

\begin{document}
%
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Indhold}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{NMR - kort teori}
%
\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
    \item $x$-aksen: elektrontæthed omkring det atom, som proton(erne) er     bundet til
    \pause
    \item $y$-aksen: antal \ce{^{1}H}-kerner 
    \pause
    \item Intensitet $=$ areal (integral) under signal
    \pause
    \item Kan ``mærke'' nærliggende \ce{^{1}H}-kerner $\to$ opsplitning
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\section{Isoeugenol Acetat}
%
\begin{frame}

\end{frame}


\subsection{Syntese}
%
\begin{frame}

\end{frame}


\subsection{NMR-spektrum}
%
\begin{frame}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it works if you pass the option through the theme declaration: `\def\swidth{2.2cm}\usetheme[width=\swidth]{Hannover}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the Documentation the Hannover theme has the option width specified in the way you need it:

```
width=⟨dimension⟩ sets the width of the sidebar.
```

So replace your custom code to define the sidebar width with

```
\usetheme[width=2.2cm]{Hannover}
```

and it works fine.

Comment: Where on earth is the documentation of the Hannover theme?