# How to show only the sections in a beamer presentation with the Hannover theme?

Tags: beamer

I am making a beamer presentation using the Hannover theme. I want to have a table of contents frame after the title page, but I want to display only the sections in the table of contents sidebar that appears in this beamer theme.

Is there is a way to not show the subsections in the sidebar while displaying the complete table of contents in the TOC frame?

The reason I want to do this is because I have a lot of subsections (and subsubsections) and they will not be displayed properly anyway in the sidebar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All subsections hiding:

```
\usetheme[hideallsubsections]{Hannover}
```

Only subsections of other sections hiding:

```
\usetheme[hideothersubsections]{Hannover}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime I found an alternative way to make room for the other subsections. An obvious and easy thing to do is to just increase the width of the sidebar using, for example:

```
\usetheme[width=2cm]{Hannover}
```

Solution found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183832/width-of-sidebar-and-width-of-text).